# SDL_main linking issue with VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl

I've written some basic setup code for an OpenGL application:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <SDL.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );

    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_SetVideoMode( 800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_OPENGL );
    glViewport( 0, 0, 800, 600 );

    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    while ( true )
    {
        if ( SDL_PollEvent( &windowEvent ) )
        {
            if ( windowEvent.type == SDL_QUIT ) break;
        }

        glClearColor( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this fails to link with the following error:

```
1>SDLmain.lib(SDL_win32_main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_main
```

Linker settings:

http://puu.sh/kVae

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `main`'s full signature:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

or try implementing `_SDL_Main` instead of `main`.